# Turn a page (a UIWebView) with an animation

Tags: iphone, animation, uiwebview, core-animation

I have a webview, which shows the pages of a ebook. I want to switch from one page to the next page with a page curl animation. By now, I know how to switch the page and how to apply a page curl animation on the webview.

But how do I apply the curl animation in a way that it looks like flipping from one page to another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some [downloadable code](http://highcaffeinecontent.com/samplecode/PageCurlDemo.zip) with an example of how to do this.

Comment: hey, that code is awesome! thanks. But what about the uiwebview? this code does it for pdf...

Answer (score 2):

I think you required to use "WebKit CSS animation" for getting animation in UIWebView.

Read DashCode_UserGuide.pdf (its available on Apple 's Dev Center Resources)

Comment: You can implement UIPageViewController