# Animation on single UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uianimation

I have searched quite a bit([sample one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867060/uiwebview-and-animation), [Sample two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598307/turn-a-page-a-uiwebview-with-an-animation)) but cant seem to get the correct answer.
I have a webview on my XYZ view controller class. When i press on a button, it takes an URL from an array and re-loads the same webview. **Now I need to do the flip book animation on it. Same webview should be reloaded.** That is the webview should rotate around its own axis 180/360 degree while the loading of next url is going on. Is this possible?

Comment: Modified the question. Can this be achieved using single webview? because in "Sample two" it can be done by using three webview views.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to do.

You want the view becomes animated at the time it is recharged to reveal the new page (in the same webview of course)?

Comment: Either the view should be animated or if possible the webview itself. I am not sure if animating the webView is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Monocle JS library](http://monocle.inventivelabs.com.au/)

It's free and has some transitions for page flipping.