# iOS webview - Loading multiple files

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I'm new to iOS here..
I have created a simple app, with `UIWebview`, where i'm loading an folder from server which consists of **4 sub folders (1. CSS 2. Images 3. Audio 4. Html files)**, where i want to show the 1st file html file from the Html Files folder in the `webview` and then when the user swipes the page i want to show the next html file from the Html files folder.. Is it possible here.. I'm new to iOS please help me.

Answer (score 0):

**Swipe Effect**

Here is a base code snippet:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *mSwipeUpRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething)];

[mSwipeUpRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];

[webview addGestureRecognizer:mSwipeUpRecognizer];

[mSwipeUpRecognizer release];
```

and in .h file add:

```
<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

Now in `doSomething` method implementation, change your web NSURL and load that url again to the web view.

**For Curl Animation:**

Here are some sample links:

[How to give page curl animation in webView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178378/how-to-give-page-curl-animation-in-webview)

[Turn a page (a UIWebView) with an animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598307/turn-a-page-a-uiwebview-with-an-animation)

Comment: Thanks mrunal.. Can i able to do like Curl page..?

Comment: how can i load the files in webview one by one...which i have the folder in bundle

Comment: Create NSURL object using file path from bundle and then use.